# After publishing app in Play Store, Firestore documents successfully write, but with missing data

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, google-play

Good day!

My Android app works just fine when built as an APK and installed manually. Firestore document writes and reads work properly. After uploading to the Play Store, Firestore document reads work just fine but document writes get weird. Documents are successfully created but there are fields missing.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRQvn.jpg) is an example of a successful document write and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ioB0.jpg) is an example of a weird document write. If you can notice, the "image_file_name" field of the successful write and the "a" field of the weird write is similar. Only the "image_file_name" gets successfully written and its field name is replaced by "a" during a weird document write.

Has anybody encountered a similar problem like mine?

Any form of help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: have you checked release build manually?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried to check the release build manually. It behaves like the Play Store version.

Comment: So, may be you need to fix some proguard rules.